# How to configure Apache Directory Server without Apache Directory Studio?

Tags: ldap, apache-ds

I am new to [Apache Directory Server](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) and the official documentation about it is quite incomplete.
I know that is possible to configure the server easily using Apache Directory Studio GUI, but i want the server to be deployed on a remote server not having a graphic interface that means, no way to use apache Directory Studio.

So can someone tell me how to:

- Add a partition, a JDBM  one
- Import an ldif file of entries under that partition

i have tried to read [this](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/2.1-config-description.html) , then i have created a new partition using apache studio to see what files have been created on the disk.
Effectively, there are folders and .ldif files created with attributes listed from the documentation. The problem here is that there are some auto-generated values for mandatory attributes such as `entryCSN` from this list [list](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/2.1-config-description.html#indexes) for the file indexes.ldif

Another problem is that i want this job to be done on unix family OS, but also on windows, nevertheless, the documention is still incomplete

Comment: So you would like to create entries using a command line tool instead of using Apache Directory Studio?

Comment: sorry @030 for the delay, yes something like that, or directly by modifying configurations files.

Comment: let's consider the both cases: running and not

Answer (score 1):

One could use [OpenLDAP](https://www.openldap.org/) and ldif to create a LDAP structure using the commandline.

**If the Apache Directory server is listing to port 10389**

For example, it is possible to create a domain:

*domain.ldif*

```
dn: dc=hello,dc=world
dc: hello
o: My Company
objectclass: organization
objectclass: dcObject
```

once the file is created one could run

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=hello,dc=world" -f domain.ldif
```

**If the Apache Directory is stopped**

It is possible to copy the directory structure, change it and start the server to make changes to the apache directory server

Comment: I will try your suggestions and get back to you asap